# Command line procedure to precompile JSPs on Windows for Tomcat6?

Tags: jsp, tomcat6

**tl;dr: How can I run the Tomcat JSP compiler from a Windows command line with verbose or debug logging and compile both the JSP and the Java code?**

I want to do a simple test compilation of a JSP for a Tomcat6 environment running on Windows 2008 Server.  I'd like to do it with as little installed "stuff" (including Ant) as possible, because I'm going to do this on a build grid that has no other reason to compile any Java code.  And I'm going to throw away the compilation result when I'm done - this is just a compilation for an early sanity check.  So I really want to avoid "stuff" I don't Need-with-a-capital-N.

It should be pretty easy to run Tomcat's JSP compiler (Jasper, *aka* JspC) from the command line, but it isn't.  I've been able to convice JspC to translate the JSP to Java with the following (buried in a BAT file, but here for simplicity):

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java" ...
    ... "-classpath" ".\Jasper\lib\jasper.jar;" ...
    ... ".\Jasper\lib\servlet-api.jar;" ...
    ... ".\Jasper\lib\catalina.jar;" ...
    ... ".\Jasper\lib\tomcat-juli.jar;" ...
    ... ".\Jasper\lib\ant.jar;" ...
    ... ".\Jasper\lib\jsp-api.jar;" ...
    ... ".\Jasper\lib\jasper-el.jar;" ...
    ... ".\Jasper\lib\el-api.jar" ...
    ... "org.apache.jasper.JspC" -uriroot ./ -s  -v -l whatever.jsp
```

And of course I get a nice console message

```
Aug 20, 2013 12:34:40 PM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile INFO: Built File: whatever.jsp
```

and an `org\apache\jsp\src\whatever_jsp.java` file.  But if I add the `-compile` JspC option, which should compile `whatever_jsp.java` to `whatever_jsp.class`, I get no console output, no `.class` file, and an exit code of 1.

Obviously something's wrong.  But since nobody on the net seems to describe how to run JspC except as an Ant task, I'm one clue short of a sixpack.  And I can't seem to convince JspC to log at a verbose or DEBUG level, so while I'm sure it's some kind of setup problem, I can't get any diagnostic output.

Comment: If you run the ant task in verbose mode does it print the java command line it executes?

Comment: @MiserableVariable Nope.  That would be nice, wouldn't it?

Comment: Step through the [JspC](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/jasper/JspC.java.html) code maybe?

Comment: My guess is that the JDK's tools.jar must be in the classpath: that's where the javac compiler is.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: @MiserableVariable Yeah, it may come down to that - building the whole mess from source and tracing through it.  It's a big time investment, and I kinda hoped I'd get a "You ignorant twit, just use the --frobnicate switch" answer.

Comment: It might not be a very complex exercise if you use jdb. Just download and extract source jar, replace java with jdb, set sourcepath and set a breakpoint in execute. IDE setup is probably not lot more complicated either.