# How to translate JSP to a Servlet from the command line?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I learned that JSP files are automatically translated into Servlets by the servlet container. How can I do this translation on the command line?

What command can I run to input a JSP file and get a Servlet as output? For example:

```
$ jsp-to-servlet mypage.jsp -o MyPage.java
```

Note: I am on Linux and using Tomcat as my servlet container, if that matters.

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340673/command-line-procedure-to-precompile-jsps-on-windows-for-tomcat6

Comment: The application server you are using does matter. See the _"Web Application Compilation"_ section in the Tomcat documentation of ["Jasper 2 JSP Engine How To"](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jasper-howto.html#Web_Application_Compilation). As stated in that section, _"Using Ant is the preferred way to compile web applications using **JSPC**"_. See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/jasper/JspC.html for the Javadoc for **JspC**.